# Simple question about integrating over different volumes

Tags: calculus

Let say I've got some open ball $B(\mathbf{x}_{0}\,;\,r) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Suppose furthermore, that $A \subset B(\mathbf{x}_{0}\,;\,r)$ (a proper subset). Is the following statement always true?

\begin{equation}
\int_{B(\mathbf{x}_{0};r)} dV = \int_{A}  dV + \int_{B(\mathbf{x}_{0};r) \setminus A} dV
\end{equation}

it's pretty obvious to me that this will be usually the case. Maybe always. I'm just not sure if maybe we need some restrictions on the structure of $A$ or something.

Comment: $A$ should be measurable. It is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the above statement should hold in all cases. The intuition should be the same as for: 
$$ \int_a^cf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(x)dx+\int_b^cf(x)dx$$